# JBoss Management Realm password not working

Tags: java, jboss

I am currently working with JBoss 6.2. I am trying to add a user so that I can access the Webconsole of Jboss. This is how I added a user :

```
[user@server bin]$ ./add-user.sh 

What type of user do you wish to add? 
a) Management User (mgmt-users.properties) 
b) Application User (application-users.properties)
(a):  

Enter the details of the new user to add.
Using realm 'ManagementRealm' as discovered from the existing property files.
Username : adminuser
Password : 
Re-enter Password : 
What groups do you want this user to belong to? (Please enter a comma separated list, or leave blank for none)[  ]: admin
About to add user 'adminuser' for realm 'ManagementRealm'
Is this correct yes/no? yes
Added user 'adminuser' to file '/local/jboss-eap- 6.2/standalone/configuration/mgmt-users.properties'
Added user 'adminuser' to file '/local/jboss-eap-6.2/domain/configuration/mgmt-users.properties'
Added user 'adminuser' with groups admin to file  '/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/configuration/mgmt-groups.properties'
Added user 'adminuser' with groups admin to file '/local/jboss-eap-6.2/domain/configuration/mgmt-groups.properties'
Is this new user going to be used for one AS process to connect to another AS process? 
e.g. for a slave host controller connecting to the master or for a Remoting     connection for server to server EJB calls.
yes/no? no
[user@server bin]$
```

I have tried this a number of times but when I access the server using:
    server:9001/console/

It does not log me in.

How can I troubleshoot this ? Are there any relevant logs I can look into ? I even restarted JBoss but it did not help.

I can see that the entry exists in mgmt-users.properties.
    adminuser=e6f48b3bbae149b83f233b4351242604